# EC2 public IP address does not match Route 53 record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a customer who has an EC2(VPC) server. When I checked the infrastructure I found out that the EC2 public IP address is not the same as attached to a server domain in Route 53 (it is not Elastic Ip Address).

Why is the EC2 IP address (IPv4 Public IP) not the same to the one in Route53 Record A and yet it is pointing to the same server?

Comment: Are you sure it's directly points to your instance? Maybe there is some proxy in the way or a load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched and a Public IP address is *enabled*, a public IP address will be assigned to the instance. If the instance is stopped and started, it *might* receive a different public IP address.

To obtain a static (non-changing) IP address:

- Create an Elastic IP Address
- Assign it to the Amazon EC2 instance

The Elastic IP address will replace the public IP address.

If there is a Record Set in Amazon Route 53 that associates a domain name with an IP address, it is your responsibility to update the record when the target instance IP address changes. There is no automatic ability to change the Record Set.

So, why is the IP address in Route 53 not the same as the instance Public IP address? It's probably because nobody updated the Record Set in Route 53 when the IP address changed.